# How to add a constant to all the initialized weights of a tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, initializer

If I wanted to a value, say epsilon, to all of my initialized weights, how might be the best way to approach this? Normally, I do not define an initializer, which causes Tensorflow to default to the glorot_uniform_initializer() (Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/glorot_uniform_initializer )

Instead of having my values initialize in a uniform way centered around zero, I want them to be centered around some epsilon. That epsilon value would be dependent on the number of values in the initial weight matrix.

Do you suggest that I just change the "seed" parameter in the glorot_uniform_initializer? Or might there be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `seed` parameter is the random seed, that's not going to help you.

I'd suggest once you run `sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )` or similar, that is, *after* the weights are initialized, get a pointer to the weight tensor of the layer in question, and use [`tf.assign_add()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign_add) to modify the weight values by a constant ***ε***.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a customized initializer:

```
def add_constant_initializer(base_initializer, epsilon):
    return lambda *a, **kw: base_initializer(*a, **kw) + epsilon
tf.get_variable(
    'MyVar', shape=(...), dtype=...,
    initializer=add_constant_initializer(tf.glorot_uniform_initializer(), epsilon))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `random_uniform_initializer` and customize it to your needs. You just need to provide it the `minval` and `maxval` that you want. If you want to set it to use the same range as a glorot uniform initializer plus a small `epsilon`, then just set minval and maxval to `epsilon+-sqrt(6 / (fan_in + fan_out))`. See the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_uniform_initializer) for details.